# How to get redirected to correct page with silex?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, routes, silex

When I go to http://www.example.com/new/index.php/login/
(please note `/index.php/` as part of the url.)
After successful login, I get redirects to http://www.example.com/new/welcome/
and that's correct.

but the login screen url should not have `/index.php/` as this is Silex restapi.

But when I try login without `/index.php/` that would be 
http://www.example.com/new/login/
after login this time, I get redirected to `new/index.php` instead of `/welcome/` like last time.

Please help.

my code is below:

Index.php:

```
$app = Silex\Application;
$app->mount('/login', new Routers\Login());
$app->run();
```

Routers\Login.php:

```
namespace Routers;
use Silex\Application;
use Silex\Api\ControllerProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request ;

class Login implements ControllerProviderInterface
{
      public function connect(Application $app)
      {
      // creates a new controller based on the default route
      $controllers = $app['controllers_factory'];
      $controllers->get('/', 'Controllers\\Login::index');
      $controllers->post('/', 'Controllers\\Login::validate');

      return $controllers;

      }
}
```

Controllers\Login.php:

```
namespace Controllers;
use Silex\Application;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;


class Login {

      public function index(Request $request, Application $app) 
      {
             return $app['twig']->render('login.html');
      }


      public function validate(Request $request, Application $app) 
      {

             // validation goes here
             if ( // invalid ) {
                 return $app['twig']->render('login.html');
             } else {
                 // valid 
                 header("Location: /welcome");
                 exit;
             }
     }
}
```

htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

EDIT:
I guess I discovered the issue, the login form is:

```
 <form method="post" action="index.php">
```

instead of posting data to http://www.example.com/new/login
So how the action url must be? I tried action="/new/login" and it doesn't work. I get no route for POST /login. but this is defined in Routers/Login.php, so why should I get this?
Please advise.

EDIT2:
How can I have named routes in my Routers\Login.php as I am using organized controllers with mount like

```
$controllers->get('/', 'Controllers\\Login::index');
```

it seems it doesn't accept bind()? Does organized controllers support named routers?

Comment: do you use twig as template engine? Also, instead of using header location to redirect, you can use RedirectResponse.

Comment: Yes, twig. Please give an example with RedirectResponse.

Comment: i advice you to see ```path()``` in twig documentation, so you will be able to use it in your ```action="{{ path('login') }}"``` and use the good path.

Comment: I see no such function on docs. please give the direct link.

Comment: can have a look here: https://silex.symfony.com/doc/1.3/providers/url_generator.html

Comment: When I use bind() like $controllers->get('/', 'Controllers\\Login::index')->bind('login'); I get "No route found for "GET /login":" but without bind() it works fine. What is wrong?

Comment: bind is not the route (so /login won't work), its just a name you can use for path('login')

Comment: I know but as path() requires a name, how to have a named route with $controllers->get('/', 'Controllers\\Login::index'); ?

Comment: Please see "EDIT2" in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to let silex find the right route for you,

bind a name to your route declaration:

```
$controllers->get('/', 'Controllers\\Login::index')->bind('login');
```

and use it in your twig template

```
<form method="post" action="{{ path('login') }}">
```

It should find the url you need.

Comment: As I said in EDIT2, it does not accept bind() on that line within Router/Login.php. Any idea?

Comment: Should it be a bug as I described in their github?

Comment: it works for me, so i don't think its a bug.```when I add bind() I get no route error without bind() it works fine``` what exactly does not work when you have the bind? Which route cause you errors?

Comment: I guess my mistake was that I defined the same name for both get and post of login router? name must be unique for each get and post?

Comment: If I have a something like /login/{id} in router then what should I have as second parameter id of path()?

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47190538/how-to-have-twig-path-with-silex-slug

Comment: answered, but you are not supposed to comment here, to bring me to answer another question. Its not "on demand" QA here.